# Looping Cubes & Adding Material (Away3D)

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, flash-builder, away3d, cubes

I'm trying to create a loop of cubes and apply a ColorMaterial to the surface. The main actionscript class has the following method for creating the loop. There is an external class file called Building which is responsible for the shape and ColorMaterial. Unfortunately, I seem to be doing something wrong. Flash Builder is not showing any warnings or errors. But when I run a test, all I get is black screen.

```
        private function buildCity():void
    {
        var citySize:int = 1800;
        var buildingSize:int = 100;
        var roadSize:int = 50;
        // Loop across in the x direction and again in the z direction

        for(var cityX:int=citySize/2;cityX<citySize/2;cityX+=buildingSize+roadSize) 
        {
            for(var cityZ:int=citySize/2;cityZ<citySize/2;cityZ+=buildingSize+roadSize) 
            {
                // Create buildings
                var building:Building = new Building();

                // Position it
                building.x = cityX;
                building.z = cityZ;

                // Add to the scene
                view.scene.addChild(building);
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Building class responsible for the shape and material**

```
package
{
import away3d.entities.Mesh;
import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
import away3d.primitives.CubeGeometry;


public class Building extends Mesh
{
    public function Building()
    {
        super(new CubeGeometry(50,100,50));
        // Make a material
        material = new ColorMaterial(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
        // Offset the y position based on height
        y = 50;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your loop parameters. For example, in your code above, you set `cityX` to `citySize / 2`, then let it iterate while `cityX < citySize / 2`.

Since `cityX >= citySize / 2` from the start, the loop is never executed.

The same goes for the inner loop.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't change anything. I even went as far as adding a negative sign to citySize/2 but the result was still the same.

Comment: @user2461697 - Can you confirm that the loops are being run? Try logging the positions for each building. If buildings are being added, then perhaps you need to ensure the camera is actually looking in the correct direction etc...